# Adding line breaks to a jquery string parameter

Tags: jquery, parameters, line-breaks

I am trying to add a line break to a jQuery parameter string. I have tried `\n` and `+ \n +` and `<br />`. Any of these break it. Here is a sample of the code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#products').grid({
        'items' :
        [
            {
            'title'       : '256 Alaskan',
            'description' : 'Production Plant: Summit | Color Classification: Heritage Series | Size Availability: Stock: Standard *special order - queen, modular thin | Texture Availability: Grain',
            'thumbnail'   : ['assets/images/products/thumbs/alaskan.jpg', 'assets/images/products/thumbs/alaskan.jpg'],
            'large'       : ['assets/images/products/fullsize/alaskan.jpg', 'assets/images/products/fullsize/alaskan.jpg'],
            'button_list' : [],
            'tags'        : ['White']
        },
});
```

---

So in the 'description' parameter, it can only take one long string sourounded by single quotes of course.
Is there any way for me to add a line break where I have put the | (pipe) symbols?
I have tried separating into mulitiple strings but it just breaks.
Any thoughts? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution! After further digging I found the function call that creates the 'description' parameter, which was basically:

```
this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
```

By simply adding a

```
<br />
```

into the full string itself I was able to create the line breaks successfully. I think initially it was not working because I was doing it like:

```
'Production Plant: Summit' + '<br />' + 'Color Cassification: Heritage Series',
```

when all it really needed was:

```
 'Production Plant: Summit <br /> Color Cassification: Heritage Series'.
```

Hope this helps out someone else in the future. Thanks for the responses.